# Is there a canonical resource for mathematical Lorem ipsum text?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, mathematical-writing, latex

I'm designing a template intended for mathematical writing. I'd like to fill the template with [Lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) text, but would like that text to showcase some of the common ways that mathematics is typeset. I could use some randomly generated text using either LaTeX's [blindtext package](https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext?lang=en) or a [random paper generator](https://thatsmathematics.com/mathgen/) (although the phony formulas in those can get pretty crunchy). But is there some canonical mathematics text used for this purpose that has the same *meaninglessness* as Lorem ipsum? Or is there some classical text (language doesn't matter) that would be cool to use for this?

Comment: Does The Art of Computer Programming count as classical?

Comment: This question would be more on-topic on [tex.se].

Comment: Euclid's Elements. https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/bookI.html

Comment: Have you seen [the answer about mathgen](https://mathoverflow.net/a/199940/41291)?

Answer (score 14):

As a "showcase", and a test for fonts, I use [fonttest.tex](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/fonttest.tex)

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. But why did you change the link to the image? I'm having trouble viewing it on my work computer (company policy blocks various sites) but I didn't before.

Comment: changed link to imgur (I actually thought that would have been a more suspicious site than a university site...)

Comment: OP asks for a text with "same meaninglessness as Lorem ipsum". While the formula here are quite meaningless, the text certainly isn't…

Comment: sure, but I may note that the Lorem ipsum text is not completely meaningless if you happen to know Latin (it's adapted from a Cicero speech).